# Reading multiple lines at once in C

Tags: c, file

so I have a huge file thats around 1 GB. Every line counts as a query and I insert those queries into a trie once I read them. Right now I'm reading one query at a time by reading the text file line by line.The length of the lines differ from line to line.
Now I want to read multiple queries, hence multiple lines at once but I'm stuck. Any help? The code shows how I read line by line from the file.

```
fp=fopen("test.txt","r");
    if(!fp)
    {
      perror("Couldn't open the file");
      exit(1);
     }
   char chunk[1000];
   size_t len= sizeof(chunk);
   char *line = (char *)malloc(len);
   if(line == NULL){
    perror("Unable to allocate memory for the line buffer");
    exit(1);
   }
   line[0]='\0';
   while(fgets(chunk,sizeof(chunk),fp) != NULL){
        if(len - strlen(line) < sizeof(chunk)){
            len *= 2;
            if((line = realloc(line,len)) == NULL){
                perror("Unable to reallocate memory for the line buffer.");
                exit(1);
             }
        }
        strcat(line,chunk);
        if(line[strlen(line)-1 == '\n']){
            printf("%s\n",line);
            insert(root,line);

            line[0]='\0';
        }

     }
```

I have thought of keeping a count for how many lines have I read, but I'm not sure. Seems like solution has to do with something like playing with the buffer size.

Comment: Just fyi, have you ever heard of [Schlemiel the Painter](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm) ? Think about that with all those `strlen` and `strcat` calls, especially for a file so large.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Writing a function that reads N lines using `fgets` should be quite simple but I have a feeling that it's not what you are looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP's code is attempting to read all the file's lines into 1 buffer - in a fairly [inefficient manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61769839/reading-multiple-lines-at-once-in-c#comment109259124_61769839).

Usually this is not wise for files on the order of 1 GByte and better to operate on a few lines (or 1) at a time.

If one still wants to read the entire file into a buffer, find its length (best by some [`fstat()` like call](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat)), allocate and then use 1 `fread()`.  An alternate Linux way is [mmap](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mmap).  Then process the buffer for lines.

---

Exploit: `line[strlen(line)-1 == '\n']` is UB should the first character read is surprisingly a *null character*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand the question, but you can youse read and write instead of fgets in this way:

```
   int fd, lung; /* fd, n read bytes */
   char buf[N]; /* how to save data */
   /* open file */
   if ( (fd = open(“s.c”, O_RDONLY)) == -1)
   { perror(“s.c”); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
   /* open file OK */
   while ((lung = read(fd,buf,N))>0){
      …
   }   
   if ( lung == -1)
   { perror(“s.c: read”); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```